# UIPageViewControllerDatasource method not called after manually setting new view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using `UIPageViewController` to display a series of `UITableView` objects each representing data of a certain date. You can scroll horizontally from one date to the next or the previous date which works perfectly. When the user selects a date from a separate menu a new `UITableViewController` is set. The problem is when now sliding left `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:` is not called again which results in displaying a `UITableView` with the previous date of the table view which was displayed before manually selecting a new date.

An example: when entering the scene the displayed date is 2014/10/15. When scolling back 2014/10/14 is displayed and when scrolling forth 2014/10/15 is displayed again. So far, so good. Now 2014/10/21 is selected and displayed. When scrolling back 2014/10/20 should be displayed but 2014/10/14 is displayed instead. Anyone who had this problem, too?  I supposed there's some caching technique behind the scenes.

```
- (UIViewController *) pageViewController: (UIPageViewController *) pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController: (RTNewsTVController *) viewController {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return [[RTDishesTVController alloc] initWithDate: [viewController.selectedDate datePlusDays: -1]];
}

- (UIViewController *) pageViewController: (UIPageViewController *) pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController: (RTNewsTVController *) viewController {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return [[RTDishesTVController alloc] initWithDate: [viewController.selectedDate datePlusDays: 1]];
}

- (void) didSelectDate: (NSDate *) date {
    RTNewsTVController *currentController = [[RTNewsTVController alloc] initWithDate: date];
    [self setViewControllers: @[currentController] direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

Comment: In one case your `initWithDate:` refers to `vcDate`, in another case it uses `viewController.selectedDate`.  Could your problem lie there?

Comment: I used vcDate for debugging reasons. It's been removed. Please see the edited code.

Comment: Does the delegate method `willTransitionToViewControllers:` get fired? Can you use that to reconfigure the view controller to the right date?

Comment: willTransitionToViewControllers: does get fired. So you suggest checking if the view controller that is beeing transitioned to has a date that's earlier or later than the current date and reset it to the apropriate date?

Comment: Yes, though I confess it feels like a hack.  Your `viewControllerBefore` method ought to work.

Comment: Have just seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26528433/3985749) to another question, which might help with your problem.